# Selling app resources outside of ipad app

Tags: ipad, resources

Here's my situation: I'm making an app for iPad which uses image libraries. The app comes with a few libraries. I want to sell additional libraries from my website. An image library contains only png files, nothing else.

The app will have an "Activate" button so if the user buys an library they can activate it from within the app. The app connects to our server via web services and validates the activation code.

The image libraries (since they can be huge) are copied in iTunes to the documents directory for the app.

My question is: does Apple have a problem with allowing me to sell additional image libraries on my website and have the user activate it and copy the files to the documents directory within the app (which I expose within the app) or is this an infringement of their policies?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes it is allowed but ONLY with in-app purchsae. dont make a seperate store

Answer (score 1):

*Edit*: Because @Kris Gellci was so eager to prove he's answer is correct, I took the time and search for the exact paragraph in the App Store Review Guide which speaks about this.

> 11 Purchasing and currencies
>
> 11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
>
> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be
>   rejected
>
> 11.3 Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected

This way you can see for yourself if it applies to you. There is more [here](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies).

---

Yes, they have a problem with that. You need to use in app purchases so that they can take their share out of what you sell. Think about it this way, if they would allow it, everybody would put their apps free with content and unlocks paid and Apple would be left out. More details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Nowhere in that documentation do i see apple forbidding users to download material that they have purchased on a website.  You are simply going off of what you think apple would do and not based off of their guidelines or proof that many apps already include downloadable content that you can purchase via third party services.

Comment: Well, those docs were for in app purchases only. There are still apps that *sell* content outside only because they were doing that before in app purchases were out, so they are bound by a different contract, however, they can't update or add new features, and Apple is putting pressure on them to change their system. I know because I worked on such an app. I can guarantee that now, any *new* app that tries to sell outside AppStore will be rejected.

Comment: In app purchases are an easy native way for developers to sell more content.  It is a service provided by apple which you are not required to use in order to sell extra content.  Just like you are not required to use iAd in order to show advertisements, you can use other third party services.  Although under your reasoning, this would not be allowed since apple would not be making money.  You are missing what the user is asking though, he wants to sell content via his website and if a user downloads his app, they can log in to their account and view the content.  This is not in app purchase.

Comment: I don't want to waste my time arguing with you. You are wrong and don't want to read and learn before posting. Read the app review guideline, it's all there, under paragraph, `11.1. Purchasing and currencies`

Comment: Again I understand that but the user is inquiring about making content available to paying customers of his website, not paying for content through an application. The guidelines state that you can not put buy buttons in your application and then use other services to process the order, they say nothing about paying users of a website being allowed to access the content that they paid for on that website through an app.

Comment: To clarify a little further: I'm not trying to circumvent Apple's guidelines. I just think that this is the easiest way for me to technically accomplish what I need.

The image libraries are just png files, they do not in any way enhance the app, but the user will have more choices to choose from when inserting images into the scenes if more libraries are available. The issue is that these libraries will be developed through time, they are not all available at app launch

If I use an in-app purchase, is there a mechanism for downloading these image files to user's device. Images can take 50mb?

Comment: from the second link I've gave you: "In-App Purchase only collects payment. You must provide any additional functionality, including unlocking built-in features or downloading content from your own servers." So, the images will be on your server, you can have an 1GB in-app purchase for all they care.

Comment: ok, then how do I update with Apple new image libraries and make them available? This is an ongoing process. Secondly, what mechanism does Apple have in place for the downloads and verification that user has downloaded all content (since this may be large)? Thanks